# draw.io: How to change the size of the column in the entity relationship.

Tags: draw.io

I have an entity relationship table.
The first entry in the first column is AAAAAAAAA but it is not shown completely, only the half of it. I tried to resize the table, but only the second column gets bigger but not the first one. How do I resize the first column to the size of the first record there?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming related questions. You want webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/draw.io